# HAML - how to display the value of a variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a variabla var.  If I try to output its value in HAML like =val then I just get the string value of the object which looks like this: `#<ShortenedUrl:0x118c50fa`.

But how do I get the value that is in there?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it contains an actual url as the value.  So I was expecting a url that it contains.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev also, I have a line like this in my code =f.url_field :fqdn_url, {:readonly => true} and I think that :fqdn_url variable has the url too.  Is there a way to print out the value of that?

Comment: @Genadinik if you’ve found a solution you should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you may want the `.inspect` method.

```
= val.inspect
```

That will show you something like:

```
#<ShortenedURL @url="the url", @count=0, @etc="etc">
```

Of course, if you want to dive in to specifics (for example, you only want to show someone the `url` attribute (or whatever attribute you may have), then use that method:

```
= val.url
```

Which will show:

```
the url
```

Answer (score 14):

Using Haml

```
%h2
  #{@project.name}
```

or

```
%h2
  #{org.id}
```